# Get the ip address from ifconfig

Tags: linux, alias, dotfiles

I was updating my shell dot file, and I thought that it would be nice to have an alias that show just my ip.
I usually connect with wifi, which is on wlan0 and it's the last "block" of devices.

So I've something like this:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:71:d9:d3:28:9d  
          inet addr:192.168.1.16  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6e71:d9ff:fed3:289d/64 Scope:Link
```

And I want my Bcast Address.

With this command i can get it:

```
alias ip="ifconfig | grep Bcast | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f14 | cut -d':' -f2"
```

But I don't like this. Is there a more clean way to do it?

Comment: If you are certain that `wlan0` is the interface you are using, the following does the trick: `ifconfig wlan0|sed -n 's/^.*Bcast:\(.*\) .*$/\1/p'`. Is this neater?

Comment: Yes, much better then using 4 commands. But could you please explain it? Thanks

Comment: I'll need to do it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are certain that `wlan0` is the interface, then you can return the information for just this interface with:

```
ifconfig wlan0
```

Now that you have only one line with `Bcast:` in it (eliminating `tail`) you can use `sed` to combine the `grep` and `cut` functions:

```
ifconfig wlan0 | sed -n 's/^.*Bcast:\(.*\) .*$/\1/p'
```

In this case, `sed -n` eliminates the routine printing of lines from input, and the search string matches the whole line, while marking what lies between `Bcast:` and the next space: the substitution is this marked field only, and `/p` overrides the `-n` and forces printing. Note that to assign this string to an alias you will need to use double quotes and escape some of the characters with back-slash, or use single quotes, replacing those in the above command by `'\''` (though you can omit the resultant final `''`).

Finally, if you want to make sure that `wlan0` is the interface you want, and there are no others configured for internet access, then you can find out which interface is being used (you may need to install `networkctl`):

```
networkctl status | sed -n 's/^.*Gateway: .* on \(.*$\)/\1/p'
```

This uses `sed` on the `networkctl` output similarly to before. Now you can combine them:

```
ifconfig $(networkctl status |\
  sed -n 's/^.*Gateway: .* on \(.*$\)/\1/p')|sed -n 's/^.*Bcast:\(.*\) .*$/\1/p'
```

This is hardly neat, but it covers most of the bases - in particular, if your wireless isn't working and you use Ethernet instead, it should still work. If you have both interfaces working together, it becomes more complicated still: I'll leave you to work it out (hint: you'll need to use `/Gateway/,$` as the line range for the `s` command, and a way to exclude the IPv6 entries).

Comment: The output of `ip -4 -o dev wlan0` may be easier to parse

Comment: @TeunVink - My version of `ip` (Ubuntu 15.04) doesn't have `dev` as an object. The information is in `ip -4 -o addr`, but I don't think this is any easier to parse.